# How to make good money with software

Tags: software-industry, salary

I often hear or read statements like this:

> I used to spend a lot of time with computers when I grew up and I became a programmer. My company pays me surprisingly well.

As if they are suspecting an error in payment and wonder why they are paid so well. It could also be humble bragging, though.

On the other side there is my own experience: offering my own programming services on my website and nobody cares, offering my programming services on upwork and having to work for degrading pay.

What am I missing here? Of course, I have never seen a paycheck of those claiming their high income, but a Tesla, a huge house and frequent travel to holiday destinations do not pay themselves and to get the credit, there must be *some* gurantee for the credit company to make sure they get their money back.

But what matters more for me is how I reproduce this for myself.

Given the normal tone in this forum, in general, I ignore condescending replies and downvotes, so to be heard and read, you need to write something useful to me.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere No, I am not. Now whether you are employed or not, the money seems to be there that employees can be paid that well. So it should be there for the self-employed aswell, shouldn't it? In other words, if I can offer, what other companies can, I will tap into the same money pool that seems to be very deep.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere So your statement is that marketing is the be all and end all. What does marketing for software development look like, though?

Comment: Keep in mind that very few people actually work on software alone. To get to the deep money pits, you usually need a very good team, too.

Comment: Why not make evil money?

Comment: @T.Sar How do you make your service worth a lot? Is it huge projects, but not many or one scaleable service for 1 USD per month?

Comment: @HeikoHanisch That's entirely up to you. You can make a bazillion money with a "free" service like Facebook, for example, or with a ultra-high premium software like AUTOCAD. You'll have to find what make you strong and work on that.

Comment: On the subject of Upwork, you have to realize that you are competing with skilled developers from potentially much lower economies who can afford to charge less and still do well.  I wouldn't view upwork as a way to get paid well in most markets.

Comment: @T.Sar - AutoCad is far from ultra-high premium software anymore, and hasn't been for about 20 years.

Comment: @JonCuster While I can't speak for the recent quality of AutoCad, the monthly fee is over 200 bucks per user. That's not cheap by any means.

Answer (score 4):

Personally, I know of two ways to make money as a software developer. Obviously, there might be more, but I'm not familiar with them.

---

**Sell a product**

This is how I make money. I have a few line-of-business products that help my customers run their business. It helps them save money, so they are willing to pay money for (a) purchasing a license and (b) purchasing a maintenance contract.

Note that (fun) software development is only part of the deal. The other (tedious, boring) part is *selling stuff* and *finding out what your (potential) customers actually need*, which is equally important, unfortunately. Just putting up a web page and waiting for customers to find you and send you their money is just not enough.

---

**Work in a company**

That's how my employees make money. What's important to me is that

- they are smart (I can give them a problem and they understand it and eventually solve it),
- they are reliable (I don't need to double-check everything they do - otherwise I might just as well do it myself) and
- they are interested in a long-term relationship (so they can fix a problem in a piece of software they wrote a few years ago).

If these criteria are met, I'm willing to pay good money, because then I can spend more time developing new products and selling stuff. If any one of these points is not satisfied and I end up spending *more* time managing them and fixing their deliverables than I would just doing their job in the first place, it's obviously not a good idea to hire them.

Comment: I would add supporting your product to the (tedious, boring) part, critical to the success of any product.

Answer (score 3):

Having spent time with computers as a kid isn't the only criterion to become a successful software developer.

There is the obvious "hard" skills like programming, modelling and knowledge about software architecture, but as important are soft skills.

Non-technical skills and traits include:

- Business awareness of the domain they are in
- Project- and Self-Management and prioritization skills
- People skills
- Self-awareness, introspection skills and conscientiousness

Answer (score 2):

Connections , Connections, Connections

use your strengths and staff your weaknesses

Business is not just HAVING a product, its more to be able to SELL the product

Find salesperson with connections and open up partnership

You will do the work, and he / she will sell it

Comment: Can you share a good example where this was applied?

Comment: @HeikoHanisch Microsoft. Apple. Amazon. Almost everything Tesla does. Most business become big not because they have an amazing product, but because they make others believe they have an amazing product.

Comment: @HeikoHanisch Every successful business in the last 20+ years. At least one of the founders is with connections and / or salesperson in essence. Products are nether 100% when coming out to the market.  Maybe other examples out there, but they only strengthen this rule.

Answer (score 1):

Self-employed and online you're competing against a bunch of people willing to work cheaply whether because they lack experience, or they're desperate, or because they live somewhere where they can afford to.

You can make a lot of money in any profession self-employed, but to do so you need a network willing to pay what you ask. You don't find those out of nowhere advertising online unless you're a niche expert, you build them based on trust and good work.